# Query post type created by a plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, the-events-calendar

I'm trying to query some fields from a custom post-type created by "The Events Calendar" plugin, in my footer.php.  The post-type is called 'tribe_events'.  Here's my query, which is currently showing me nothing.

```
                    <ul class="evul" >
                        <?
                        $query = new WP_Query
                       ( array( 'post_type' => 'tribe_events') );
                        if ($query->have_posts() ) 
                        : while ($query-> have_posts()) :
                         $query->the_post();
                        ?>

                     <li class="evlist" id="evli-">
                    <span class="evdate" id="evspd-">
                        <?  echo tribe_get_venue();?>
                    </span>
                    <span class="evtype" id="evspt-">
                        <? echo tribe_get_events_link(); ?>:
                    </span>
                    <span class="evdesc" id="evspds-">
                        <? echo the_title(); ?>
                    </span>
                       </li><br>

 <?  endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); 
 ?>

                    </ul>

                </div>
```

I'm not sure what else I need to do. Is there a step I'm missing since it's from a plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: are you getting any error or warning messages - https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am not getting any errors or messages and the log is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach should work I think, I would check only if short PHP open tags `<?` are working in your server configuration because they are deprecated for some time and should be replaced with `<?PHP`.

Alternatively have you tried the approach from the [plugin's docs](https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/using-tribe_get_events/#basic-usage) using the build in function `tribe_get_events()`:

```
<ul class="evul" >
<?PHP
// Ensure the global $post variable is in scope
global $post;

$events = tribe_get_events();

// Loop through the events: set up each one as
// the current post then use template tags to
// display the title and content
foreach ( $events as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );

    // This time, let's throw in an event-specific
    // template tag to show the date after the title!
    ?>
    <li class="evlist" id="evli-">
        <span class="evdate" id="evspd-">
            <?= tribe_get_venue($post) ?>
        </span>
        <span class="evtype" id="evspt-">
            <?= tribe_get_events_link($post) ?>:
        </span>
        <span class="evdesc" id="evspds-">
            <?= get_the_title($post); ?>
        </span>
    </li>
    <?PHP
}
?>
</ul>
```